# swift/objective c -- имитация нажатия горячей клавиши на Mac-е по запросу с телефона

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, macos

Задача:

С телефона(iOS) подать сигнал на комп(OSX) и там сымитировать нажатие горячей клавиши...

Вопрос:

1. Возможно ли это сделать БЕЗ программы-приемника сигнала? Если да, то каким макаром? (на сколько я знаю, там довольно тесное взаимодействие осей на телефоне и компе, потому допускаю что такая возможность есть). Если же нету такой возможности...
2. С чего посоветуете начинать? Как реализовать передачу сигнала на комп спаренный с телефоном (в программу-приемник)? Как реализовать максимальное сохранение энергии?(например, использования блютуза или что-то другое)

---

**Чисто для себя(неважная информация, можно не читать):**

Имитация нажатий клавиш в Swift 3:

```
let src = CGEventSource(stateID: CGEventSourceStateID.hidSystemState)

let cmdd = CGEvent(keyboardEventSource: src, virtualKey: 0x38, keyDown: true)
let cmdu = CGEvent(keyboardEventSource: src, virtualKey: 0x38, keyDown: false)
let spcd = CGEvent(keyboardEventSource: src, virtualKey: 0x31, keyDown: true)
let spcu = CGEvent(keyboardEventSource: src, virtualKey: 0x31, keyDown: false)

spcd?.flags = CGEventFlags.maskCommand;

let loc = CGEventTapLocation.cghidEventTap

cmdd?.post(tap: loc)
spcd?.post(tap: loc)
spcu?.post(tap: loc)
cmdu?.post(tap: loc)
```

И по линке довольно [большой список](https://bitbucket.org/cabalistic/ogredeps/src/a623a62ae85c/src/ois/src/mac/MacKeyboard.cpp?fileviewer=file-view-default) цифр-значений клавиш.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Насколько мне известно, такой возможности без программы-приёмника нет.
2. Опять же по моему опыту стандартные сетевые API Cocoa и Cocoa Touch (NSURLSession) предназначены для взаимодействия через Интернет. Этот способ будет куда проще в освоении, да и по энергосбережению лучше, чем Bluetooth, так как сетевой модуль и так работает, а Bluetooth нужно включать отдельно.
   Если же Bluetooth необходим (например, для скорости или безопасности), то для этого существует фреймворк Core Bluetooth, на Apple Developer по нему достаточно информации для ваших задач.
   Не знаю, стоит ли сильно беспокоиться об энергосбережении, стандартные средства операционной системы должны об этом позаботиться в данном конкретном случае. Для более конкретных советов по этому поводу обратитесь к статье Best Practices For Interacting With Remote Peripheral Device в документации к Core Bluetooth.